# Do functions within a package share the same sub-functions?

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2

I'm trying to understand how this package (`darksky`, found here: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/darksky) works.

It contains these two scripts in the R folder:

1. `aaa.R`, and
2. `get-current-forecast.R`

The former (`aaa.R`) contains a subfunction called `convert_time`. This is being called by the latter (`get-current-forecast.R`) and seems to work but `aaa.R` is not imported/refferred to by `get-current-forecast.R`.

How is this working? Are all subfunctions available to other functions in the same package?

Comment: Packages don't work the same as sourcing R files in an interactive session. All the functions defined in every .R file in a package are registered in the package's namespace, which gets attached when you run `library(foo)`. So when a function in the package calls some other function, R first looks in that package's namespace for function by that name.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. So, basically all subfunctions are available everytime the package is loaded. Probably should be a bit more careful when defining subfunctions inside a function.

Comment: Functions defined inside another function are different. R won't see and register those in the package namespace. They would be available only within the enclosing function.

Comment: Well in that case the package shouldn't work: `convert_time` is defined inside `aaa.R` and is being referred to directly in `get-current-forecast.R` without calling/importing `aaa.R`

Comment: No. `aaa.R` is a file, not a function.In that _file_ several functions are defined. A function defined _inside a function_ would be something like `function(x) {blah; foo <- function(y) y;}`. Files are not functions. Maybe you're used to matlab...?

Comment: You're right, I am more used to Matlab. When making my own package, I kept the function name and file name the same and each file had only one function so I got all confused with this one. This clears it all up, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages don't work the same as sourcing R files in an interactive session. All the functions defined in every .R file in a package are registered in the package's namespace, which gets attached when you run `library(foo)`. So when a function in the package calls some other function, R first looks in that package's namespace for function by that name.

However, functions defined inside another function are different. R won't see and register those in the package namespace. They would be available only within the enclosing function.

For example,

```
foo <- function(x){
  y <- x+1
  bar <- function(z){
    z+1
  }

  bar(y)
}
```

If `foo` were defined in some .R file in a package, the function `foo` would be visible, but `bar` would be visible only within `foo`.